# Why some people don't check for NULL after calling malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, null, malloc

Some time ago I downloaded a sourcecode from the Internet. There were several malloc calls, and after that there was no check for NULL. As far as I know you need to check for NULL after calling malloc.

Is there a good reason for somebody not check for NULL after calling malloc? Am I missing something?

Comment: This is why exceptions are superior to error codes, by the way.

Comment: Because there are much more important things that come before it: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/chasing-a-phantom-checking-the-return-of-malloc/

Comment: Just one more piece of information: the code mentioned in the question was created by a Microsoft MVP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Jens Gustedt mentioned in a comment, by the time `malloc()` returns an error your program is likely to be in a heap of trouble already.  Does it make sense to put in a bunch of error handling code to handle the situation, when the program is likely not going to be able to do much of anything anyway? For many programs the answer might be 'no', for others it might be very important to do something appropriate.

You can try allocating your memory through a simple 'malloc-or-die' wrapper function that guarantees that the allocation succeeds or the program will terminate:

```
void* m_malloc(size_t size)
{

    void* p;

    // make sure a size request of `0` doesn't trigger
    // an error situation needlessly 
    if (size == 0) size = 1;

    p = malloc(size);

    if (!p) {
        // attempt to log the error or whatever
        abort();
    }

    return p;
}
```

One problem that you then run into is that there's not much you can reliably do except maybe terminate the program. Even logging the problem is likely to require some memory allocation, so the logging facility will probably have its own problems (unless your allocation failure is due to trying to allocate an unreasonably large block of memory).

You might try to solve that issue by allocating a 'fail-safe' block early in your program that can be freed when you need to log the problem (I think there are quite a few programs that use this strategy). But how much work you are willing to put into this kind of error handling depends on your specific needs. If your program needs to ensure that something of significant complexity is done when `malloc()` returns an error, you'll need to have corresponding safeguards to make sure you *can* do those things in a very low-memory situation.  Generally this means additional complexity, and it may not always be worth the effort.

Answer (score 6):

People don't check because they're lazy, it makes their code uglier, and they don't want to figure out how to recover from errors everywhere.

I've heard a few programmers say, "If I can't malloc a block the system is going to crash soon anyway because VM is full, so why should I bother checking?"

I disagree. You should check for errors, even if it means just logging the error and calling exit() or throwing an exception. While we were trending towards systems with huge disks and always-on paged memory, the industry has flipped and now we have smartphones and tablets with limited RAM and no on-demand paging. Plus even on the desktop our datasets have grown so much that sometimes malloc will fail.

If you don't want to add extra lines of code everywhere, just write your own malloc replacement that calls malloc and checks for errors and use it instead of malloc.

Answer (score 3):

They just don't care about unexpected crashes!

When you do malloc, it's very likely you are going to store something immediately. So if you don't check for NULL, then program may crash subsequently when trying to store something there.

This is unlikely in small programs where malloc hardly fails when requested for small amount of memory. So the malloc doesn't return NULL.

But it's usually good to *practice* the `NULL check` for malloc even in small programs, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more memory and `malloc` can not give you more can you do anything about it?
I guess exit gracefully.
But if you exit, I guess they think it doesn't really matter how you exit (might as well crash and avoid, the what they think as "overhead" for checks for null).
Perhaps the functionality was such that they didn't have any need for cleanup code?
I don't agree though. You should check for `NULL` on malloc's return